# Why can you access static field before it is defined through a method in Java?

Tags: java

I ran into an interesting thing:

```
static {
    System.out.println(test);     // error cannot reference a field before it is defined
    System.out.println(cheat());  // OK! 
}

private static boolean cheat() {
    return test;
}

private static boolean test = true;

public static void main(String args[]) {}
```

The first way is wrong and both your compiler and IDE will tell you it's wrong. In the second case, cheating is OK, but it actually defaults the field `test` to `false`. Using Sun JDK 6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is defined in the [JLS 8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3). In particular:

> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is used [...] if the usage occurs in a [...] static initializer of C.

When you call `cheat()` you go around that rule. This is actually the 5th example in [the list of the examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e10466) of that section.

Note that `cheat()` will return false in the static initializer block because `test` has not been initialised yet.

Comment: +1. I was looking for this reference, by that time I got down votes.

Comment: @Andremoniy I was writing that.

Comment: @assylias, Is there a similar example for Java 6?

Comment: @mdobrinin It works the same - this section was already part of [JLS v5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.3.2.3) so no change since java 5 on that front.

Answer (score 3):

Because class loading works in this order:

- Loads Class definition (methods, signatures)
- Allocates the memory for the static variable references (for `test`) - does not initialize yet
- Executes the `static` initializers (for variables) and the `static` blocks - in order they are defined

So, by the time you have reach`static` block, you have the method definition ready, but don't have the variable ready. With `cheat()` you're actually reading an uninitialized value.

Answer (score 1):

This is the generic steps by which class loading happens.

1. Loading  - Load the class to memory
2. Verification - checks binary representation of a class e is correct
3. Preparation -  create the static fields for the class and initialize those fields to their standard default values.
4. Initializing - will invoke static initializers and initializers for static fields

After preparation, your test will be false.Then before you assign static variable to true, your static block will execute.That is why you are getting false.

Try making your static variable final.In that case,you will be getting true.This is because your compiler itself will embed the value in bytecode(since the field is final) as part of optimisation